# Angular: Changing values of boolean in array

Tags: angular

I have a problem where i have an array that is used to show a grid pattern on the website.

```
randomNumber: number


objects = object[] = [
{image: '', message: '', show: true},
{image: '', message: '', show: true},
{image: '', message: '', show: true},
{image: '', message: '', show: true},
{image: '', message: '', show: true}
]
```

I want to loop this array using math.random and change the value of the boolean to false and then change it back after 3 seconds.

so far i have this code

```
changeBoolean() {
  this.randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.objects.length);
}
```

So i get a number that i can use and change that boolean to false. After changing one i would like it to automaticly change another one and maximun have 2 booleans set to false at a time.

```
this.objects[this.randomNumber].show = Boolean(false);
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Ive tried multiple things but my skill in angular is not the greatest but im trying to learn

Comment: you could have another `randomNumber` - `randomNumber2` - and use it as you use the first one. Just make sure that second random number doesn't have the same value as the first

Comment: let me understand, you have an array `objects` with a property `show` and you want to randomize it so that all `show` are true except of two of them need to be `false` ? right?

Comment: I have a button that should start a function that randomly changes one boolean at a time to false and then turns it back to true after 3 seconds. as soon as it has turned the first one to false it should find a new random number to make false. After it has passed 3 seconds on the first number it should turn false and then we find a new number.

Comment: How many elements should be changed randomly at first - only 1 ? Then the randomly-changed ones should be reset to the previous state, after 3 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

### For a single element

Add `setInterval` to repeat the call after 3 seconds (here specified as `3000` milliseconds).

Also, when iterating through all elements with a `forEach` loop you can hide the particular element by setting `show = false` by index  based on a `randomNumber`.

#### Example Code

```
let that = this;
setInterval(function () {
  that.randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * that.objects.length);
  that.objects.forEach((element, index) => {
    index === that.randomNumber
      ? (element.show = false)
      : (element.show = true);
  });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: This kind of works but how do i make it so more than one element.show can be false at the same time?

Comment: Okay. then you have to use Array for multiple element.show false.
First you assign the randomNumber variable as Array.

Then repeat this line as you need to false
that.randomNumber.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * that.objects.length));


And change the condition 
index === that.randomNumber

to 
that.randomNumber.indexOf(index) > -1

Comment: Thanks, Almost there. But it doesnt revert the first one back to true after 3 seconds it just keeps flipping them all to false.

Comment: You should assign empty array after each time before push random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

### For Multiple elements

Declare a variable to collect multiple random numbers as array like `randomNumber = [];`

Then generate the random numbers and use them as follows

```js
let that = this;

setInterval(function () {
  that.randomNumber = [];
  that.randomNumber.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * that.objects.length));
  that.randomNumber.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * that.objects.length));
  
  that.objects.forEach((element, index) => {
    that.randomNumber.indexOf(index) > -1
       ? (element.show = false)
       : (element.show = true);
   });
}, 3000);
```